# My letter Q will not type. It is part of my password so I am locked out of my laptop

Tags: windows-10, laptop

I shut My Windows 10 HP laptop computer down.  Whhen I tried to go back in, the letter Q will not type! It is a part of my password. HELP!!!  I'm locked out.

Comment: Shut down, hook up a USB keyboard and start with that.

Comment: Try holding down the ALT key and typing the number 0081 for Q or 0113 for q - I don't use Windows so havn't tried it, but those numbers are the ASCII equivalents, and historically Windows has allowed you to enter characters that way.

Comment: HP keyboards can generally be replaced, though its not entirely trivial (working on laptop hardware rarely is).

Answer (score 5):

If possible use an external keyboard to type your password

Also there is a button on you loggin screen
for accessibility
press it and then use the option of on-screen keyboard
then type your password

[image]

Comment: I am literally using the On-Screen Keyboard right now because I broke the Y key.